Pearson chi square and correlation
My data are ordinal
Pearson chi squared test value is 4.664
And asymp sig is 0.97 so the data are independent
However pearson's R =-0.309
And the approx sig=0.037
Can they be independent and negatively correlated at the same time

There's something that doesn't add up. For this chi-square statistic and p-value, the df should be 1, but you mention in another comment that the df is 2. Can you simply share the contingency table on which you conducted the tests? It would be simpler to give you an answer.

"chi squared test value is 4.664 And asymp sig is 0.97 so the data are independent". I don't agree with this statement. You do not know that the data are independent. You have failed to find evidence that the observed distribution is due to chance. That is that the observed values do not differ from the expected values, by more than we would expect by chance.
The chi-square test is used for categorical data.
The Pearson correlation is used for continuous (usually) data.
If you swap the values around in the chi-square test, the result will be unchanged (so all the 1s change to 2s, all the 2s become 7s, etc). This will have a dramatic effect on the correlation.
Also, while I'm here: don't present a chi-square and p without the df - and tell us a little more about your data.

Chi person df is 2.    Also,can i use spearman correlation instead of pearson correlation for my categorical data?

You can, but it probably won't be appropriate. You should pick the analysis that matches your null hypothesis - you haven't talked about that. You shouldn't do a different analysis because you didn't like the result of the first one.
